# How to hide path inside Swift Package from Project Navigator managed by XCode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I've created Swift package, which contains a folder with an example project. Its path is not included in any target sources. Nonetheless, after opening Package.swift file in XCode, Project Navigator still shows not included paths. How to hide that obsolete folder?

[image]

Comment: Show your package.swift file.

Comment: @Paulw11[here](https://github.com/lyzkov/RxStorm/blob/master/Package.swift)

Comment: I notice that the folder name has a misspelling compared to what is in your a large file. Do you have an incorrect folder in your file system somewhere that is being picked up.

Comment: @Paulw11I have corrected that typo and problem still occurs.

Answer (score 0):

As I suppose, it is unlikely that XCode manages Navigator contents using an exclusion path from target configuration. It shows not only files specified in targets but all files included in root path. It is reasonable because the package can contain a readme file that can be edited by XCode, however it is not reasonable for files of the example project.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your folder hidden in your Swift Package by adding `.` at the begin of its name and the Project Navigator doesn't show it because by default, folders with periods at the beginning of their names are hidden in OS X and XCode as well e.g.: `.RxStormExample`.

Comment: I want to hide folder only in Navigator.